# UI AngularJS Sortable - Getting an undefined error when attaching to scope

Tags: angularjs

I am using the AngularJS UI Sortable directive and I am trying to pull the data from my view into my controller and update/stop the sorting on every click. I am creating a blank array and then attaching the `$scope.areas` to the blank array. I am able to display the content through the `ng-repeat`. However, when I `console.log(areas)`, I am getting an `undefined`.

VIEW

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="areas" class="uk-nestable"> 
        <li data-item="{{area.label}}" data-item-id="{{area.order}}" ng-repeat="area in areas">
            <div class="uk-nestable-item mainarea-blue">
                <div class="uk-nestable-handle mainarea-text-white"></div>
                <div data-nestable-action="toggle"></div>
                    <div class="list-white">{{area.label}}</div>
            </div>
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
     //create a blank array
      var tmpList = [];    

    //attaches ng-model scope to tmpList    
      $scope.areas = tmpList; 
        console.log(areas);

    //changed old sort to new sort  
      $scope.sortingLog = [];

      $scope.sortableOptions = {
    //creates a log entry of the new update view      
        update: function(e, ui) {
          var logEntry = tmpList.map(function(i){
            return i.value;
          }).join(', ');
    //displays the update  text and array
          $scope.sortingLog.push('Update: ' + logEntry);
        },
        stop: function(e, ui) {
   // this callback has the changed model
          var logEntry = tmpList.map(function(i){
            return i.value;
          }).join(', ');
          $scope.sortingLog.push('Stop: ' + logEntry);
        }
      };
```

My goal is to display the area.label in the correct sort order. For example; I have 3 unordered lists - floor, basement, kitchen and I want to change the order to basement, floor, kitchen. As I am changing the sort order it is updating and stop the sorts.

I am probably not doing the best job explaining myself so here is a similar codepen...http://codepen.io/thgreasi/pen/jlkhr.

Comment: Try `console.log($scope.areas)`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am now getting an empty array instead of undefined.

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Is it just to correct the undefined `console.log()` result? If so then it sounds like @DanielHaley has the correct solution.

Comment: Also, the reason you're getting an empty array is because `tmpList` is empty when you're doing your `console.log()`.

Comment: I would like to display the area.label in the correct order. For example; I have 3 unordered lists - floor, basement, kitchen and I want to change the order to basement, floor, kitchen. As I am changing the sort order it is updating and stopping the sort order.

Comment: In regards to the empty array, I am aware that the tmpList is empty but I am trying to attach the scope areas to tmpList not tmpList to areas.

Comment: @BV2005 I see that you don't possess enough reputation for us to continue this conversation in chat so I will ask here, have you tried assigning the `$scope.areas` to `tmpList`? (E.G. `var tmpList = $scope.areas;`) This would then make both the `tmpList` and `$scope.areas` reference the same object.

Comment: Thank you, Matt I will try that :)

Comment: @BV2005 Were you able to find a solution to your problem? If so I would encourage you to post that here :)